# Continuous Integration via Package Feed Activity

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Does DevOps support triggering a build when a new version of one of our projects dependencies becomes available? If so, how can this be configured?

In addition to triggering a build, there's also a question as to how best to update my project's packages.config file (to contain the new version number) and my project's vcxproj file so that the build actually targets the new package rather than the current one. (I'm sure I could write a script to manually perform the edits, but I'm hoping something as basic as this would have native support.)

Additional background information:
 1. I'm interested in configuring this for at least two projects. One consumes all of its dependencies via NuGet packages and the other is a node.js project and therefor uses npm packages.
 2. These NuGet and npm packages are a mix of public packages (like react-native), external private DevOps tenant feeds, and packages published privately to our own DevOps artifact package feed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the NuGet Package itself will not know about all the projects that depend on it, so no.

You could use the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) to trigger a new build for all projects you'd want to update and use the latest version from there.

Comment: While each individual package/feed doesn't know who is using it, there are several mechanisms I could see working. At the very least, a pull mechanism could be used to retrieve latest package versions periodically. Better yet, perhaps Azure, NPM, and other feed sources have a notification model allowing push notifications whenever new versions get published -- for example something similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/follow-package-notifications?view=vsts except rather than being email-based, it could easily tie into DevOps.